# How to convert and concatenate positions in an lpBuffer to end up with a hex number printed as an integer?

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port, hex, readfile, data-conversion

I am new to C++.

I have referenced 10+ stackoverflow pages citing similar problems, but no matter what I try I cannot extrapolate a solution to fit my specific problem.

I have some electronics feeding data into a serial port, of which the correctness is verified through RealTerm and XCTU. (Long story short I know that the data being sent to the port is correct)

I am accessing the serial port using CreateFile()/dcb. (The port setup code I am fairly sure is correct but if you want to see code to verify that yourself let me know)(If accessing the serial port using a different method would solve this problem, let me know)

The only action I am performing on the port is ReadFile().
The lpBuffer the ReadFile() call uses is setup as a char[].
I don't know why but it seems that each index of the char[] only accepts one byte of information.
For debug purposes I use:

```
cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) ...
```

So that it will print out to console like so:

```
lpBuffer in [...] = ...
lpBuffer in [11] = 03
lpBuffer in [12] = ff
lpBuffer in [...] = ...
```

I would like to use the concept of concatenating two strings so that I get:

03ff (1023)

I also would prefer an answer that stores the "concatenated" value in a variable, without changing the information stored in the lpBuffer/char[] (not literally concatenating it), and stores the value as an integer.

I have tried using sprintf_s(), stringstream, converting to string and using stoi.
The closest answers I have found do not seem to work for lpBuffers(char[] holding byte data as opposed to actual characters?) and also convert all indexes of the array, not specific ones only.

Please help, C++ Wizards!

Comment: *"I would like to use the concept of concatenating two strings so that I get..."* -- You're confusing single-byte values with *"strings"*.  Try `256 * lpBuffer[11] + lpBuffer[12]`, and treat this sum as an integer.

Comment: @sawdust Can you explain what the significance of 256 is?

Comment: @sawdust That does work partially btw. Using "256 * lpBuffer[11] + lpBuffer[12]" the output on the console reads in hex: 3ff

Comment: @sawdust Ignore that last comment I forgot about using "dec" to tell cout to read in decimal format! Cheers! However I would still like to know the significance of 256 here, if you care to educate me.

Comment: 256 is 2^8 or 2**8 or 2 raised to the eighth power or 0x100.  Instead of an arithmetic multiplication, you could instead use a logical shift, i.e. `(lpBuffer[11] << 8) + lpBuffer[12]`.  The shift of 8 bit positions required for the high-order byte corresponds to the bit positions occupied by the value of lpBuffer[12], i.e. the low-order byte.

Comment: @sawdust Could this "logical shift" also be explained as: literally moving all the bits in lpBuffer[11] to the left 8 times (adding nulls), to make room for replacing the bits on the end of lpBuffer[11] with the bits in lpBuffer[12]?

Comment: Yes, a byte shift is literally moving all the bits *of* lpBuffer[11] to the left 8 times, inserting zeros.  This shift operation is performed on a CPU register, and not the array element in memory.  In this case "logical" is used as the opposite of "arithmetic", i.e. preserve the sign-bit.  This distinction of logical vs arithmetic shift operations is salient at the CPU instruction level.  High-level programming can obscure such details, which can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Although some things about it are a little ugly, what you typically want to do is define a structure that describes the data as you expect it to be. So for example, let's assume your data is two longs (4-byte items) followed by two shorts (2-byte items).

```
#pragma pack(1);
struct my_input {
    long data1;
    long data2;
    short data3;
    short data4;
    // more stuff here
};
```

Then, when you read in a buffer full of data, you can cast something like this:

```
my_input *in = (my_input *)&buffer[0];
```

Then you can look at the data through the lens of that structure (so to speak) and see the types that are intended to be there:

```
std::cout << in->data4;
```

In this particular case, you have one other minor twist to deal with though: the data you're receiving is apparently in big-endian order or (as it's sometimes called) network order. Fortunately, the normal networking library provides a few functions to convert network-order data to the data used by the processor you compile it for, so (in this case) you want something like this:

```
std::cout << ntohs(in->data4);
```

There's `ntohs` for "short" (16-bit) values, as well as `ntohl` for long (32-bit) and (in most current networking stacks) `ntohll` for long long (64-bit) values.

Do note the `pragma pack(1)`. It tells the compiler not to insert any extra padding between the fields. When you're trying to match an externally defined structure, if there's any padding there, you typically want to insert it explicitly instead of trusting that the compiler will insert it where you want it.

Comment: This answer has a serious flaw: it ignores the endianness (byte order) of the CPU.  The OP has implicitly specified big endian in his example.  Whereas x86 and most ARM are little endian.